# I want to translate boostrap validation message according to different locales.(not using browser language)

Tags: javascript, aem, i18next, bootstrapvalidator, language-packs

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url=window.location.pathname;
  if(url.match("(/content/de/)(.*)")) {
          $("#btnContactUs").click(function(){
           $.getScript('/clientlib-site/js/de_DE.js', function() {
              alert("success");  
          });
    }
});
```

Here I am trying to add bootstrap-validators language pack(de_DE.js) if selected locale is de else if selected locale is en then add(en_US.js).already tried using different language packages

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AEM, it provides a I18N object for JavaScript where you could use your Dictionary entries for translation. Please have a look at the documentation: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/i18n-dev.html